# Astable Multivibrator circuit using LM741 Op Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4I0d3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The problem is here I'm not getting the output as expected.
The voltage at output terminal is constant and potential at capacitor is also not changing.

Comment: Did i miss something or there is no question here ?

Comment: jeez, what is with all those 741 questions lately, will that thing die already?

Comment: The LED should be blinking here, but it's not.

Comment: @kirankhunte Please 1) Ask a specific quesiton to help readers understand your problem 2) Write a more detailed statement of your problem. The question is a a little vauge. Please also see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There appear to be two sloppy errors in your schematic:

[image]

1. The resistor should be 1M\$\Omega\$ not 1m\$\Omega\$. Beware that SPICE will usually interpret 1M as 0.001 because it has case-insensitive roots. Use 1 MEG or 1 mega or 1000K.
2. The crossover there should be joined. The negative feedback is via R4/C1 and the positive feedback is via R1/R2. They can't feed back unless they are connected to the output. As you've shown it the op-amp will just saturate against one rail or the other and the LED will remain on or off continuously.

Answer (score 3):

This circuit will **not work**.

For a circuit to become astable, some form of feedback is needed.

I see the output of the opamp only being connected (through a resistor) to the LED. There is no feedback whatsoever.

All inputs of the opamp will be 0 V when the capacitor is discharged (which will be the starting condition in a simulator). There is no path for the capacitor to charge.

R4 has a value of 1m ohm or 0.001 ohm. That is not a realistic value.

The LED is not blinking and that is what I expect from this circuit.

It would be a miracle if it did blink !